# How to configure Subdomain DNS when using Laravel domain route on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, dns, subdomain

Please how can I configure subdomain DNS when using Laravel domain route on shared hosting.

```
     Route::domain('me.domain.com')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', function(){
           return "Hello, Welcome to my Laravel Domain Routing. Thanks You";
        });
     }]);
```

Thanks in Anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cpanel in your sharing hosting account go to the option "Add Sub Domain" create the sub domain and set the folder as your laravel public project.

### Sub domain

me.domain.com

### Root directory

/var/www/laravel_project/public/

Also you have to create the record on your DNS account if you are managing apart.

```
Type          Name             Value                       TTL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
A             domain.com       88.55.65.18 (server IP)     Automatic
A             me(sub domain)   88.55.65.18 (server IP)     Automatic
```

Comment: I've done that before asking yet it's still the same, that's way I'm seeking for help if there's need to do some DNS Configuration or Pointing..

Comment: @SamuelOluwatimilehin look at the update in the answer and tell me if helps you.

Comment: It return sub.domain.com/404